# How to have only unique options in select picker drop down?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a select picker dropdown. I'm appending option values dynamically from backend but when same values come, there are duplicate options in the drop down. I want to have only unique values in the drop down. How to check if a value already exists before appending it to the drop down?

I'm appending the value something like this:

```
$("#pid").append('<option value="'+strSplit[0]+'"selected="">'+strSplit[0]+'</option>');
$("#pid").selectpicker("refresh");
```

Comment: You would probably have to handle that in the backend.

Comment: filter you array for unique items i.e remove duplicates and then append the values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a selector to look for an existing option with the same value. If it doesn't exist, add it.

```
if ($("#pid option[value=" + strSplit[0] + "]").length == 0){
    $("#pid").append('<option value="'+strSplit[0]+'"selected="">'+strSplit[0]+'</option>');
    $("#pid").selectpicker("refresh");
}
```

Comment: This works but is there anyway to display an existing option in the select box without actually appending it. I tried using `.val` property of the dropdown but it didnt work.

Comment: `.val` isn't a property, it's a function: `$("#pid").val(option_to_select)`